# I got 2 Errors , first there is a ignored plsql statement and then there is a identifier which need to be declared?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I wanted to convert my MySQL Trigger to an Oracle Trigger but there are 2 errors which does not make any sense for me. First there is a PLSQL Statement ignored and second my identifier needs to be declared.

i tried a few things but still i got no solution.

```
CREATE  OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_Zeitraum_Termin 
BEFORE INSERT ON Termin 
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
 Termin_Anzahl_Patient int;
 Termin_Anzahl_Arzt int;
 Termin_Anzahl_Mitarbeiter int;
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(Patient_id) INTO Termin_Anzahl_Patient FROM Termin WHERE      Datum = :NEW.Datum AND Patient_ID = :NEW.Patient_ID AND Patient_ID IS NOT NULL;

IF (Termin_Anzahl_Patient > 0) 
THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR ( -20001,'Dieser Patient hat schon um diese Uhrzeit einen Termin');
END IF;

SELECT count(arzt_id) INTO Termin_Anzahl_Arzt FROM termin WHERE datum = :NEW.datum AND Arzt_ID = :NEW.Arzt_ID AND Arzt_ID IS NOT NULL;

IF (Termin_Anzahl_Arzt > 0)
THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR ( -20002,'Dieser Arzt hat schon um diese Uhrzeit einen Termin');
END IF;

SELECT count(Mitarbeiter_ID) INTO Termin_Anzahl_Mitarbeiter FROM Termin WHERE Datum = :new.Datum AND Mitarbeiter_ID = :NEW.Arzt_ID AND Mitarbeiter_ID IS NOT NULL;

IF Termin_Anzahl_Mitarbeiter > 0 
THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR ( -20003,'Dieser Mitarbeiter hat schon um diese Uhrzeit einen Termin');
END IF;

IF NEW.datum < NOW() 
    THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR ( -20004,'Dieser Patient hat schon um diese Uhrzeit einen Termin');
END IF;

  END; 
    /
```

Comment: Fehler(23,5): PL/SQL: Statement ignored                                                          Fehler(23,11): PLS-00201: identifier 'NEW.DATUM' must be declared

Comment: `NEW.datum ` should be `:NEW.datum`

Comment: oh man , i did not see that ... thanks

Comment: Do you encounter mutating table error ..?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `IF NEW.datum < NOW() THEN` with

`IF :NEW.datum < systimestamp THEN` or `IF :NEW.datum < current_timestamp THEN`, since Oracle doesn't contain `NOW()` function.

And you'd better to combine the queries into one by converting to

```
SELECT count(case when nvl(Patient_ID,-1) = :new.Patient_ID then Patient_id end ), 
       count(case when nvl(Arzt_ID,-1) = :new.Arzt_ID then Arzt_ID end ), 
       count(case when nvl(Mitarbeiter_ID,-1) = :new.Mitarbeiter_ID then Mitarbeiter_ID end ) 
  INTO Termin_Anzahl_Patient, Termin_Anzahl_Arzt, Termin_Anzahl_Mitarbeiter
  FROM Termin 
 WHERE Datum = :NEW.Datum;
```

and put them just after `BEGIN` (since those variables should be set before been used by `IF` statements) , and presuming those `ID` values are non-negative integers as ever preferred.

Comment: Yeah thanks , i did it now like that IF :NEW.DATUM < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() it works but still thanks for the solution

Comment: @zazaza yes, that's also possible as `current_timestamp`, e.g. without parentheses. You're welcome.

Comment: With the changes suggested you will get the trigger compiled, However when run it will get an "ORA-04091: table string.string is mutating ...". Ths results from the select statements referencing the table that the trigger is on.  I do not speak German (my problem) but looks like you are attempting to validate availability of time slots.  This validation needs to be into the app before the INSERT, or placing unique constraints on the particular id and time.

Comment: @zazaza - when you get that mutating table error please have a look at [the answers to the many previous questions on that topic] (https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=oracle+trigger+mutating).